# github: How to work on specific tagged release

Tags: git, github

I want to work on specific release of mongo code. git tag lists a number of tags. I want to work on ( lets say ) xyz tag and make code changes to it.

To start with

1. I create a github account and forked mongo repo in my account
2. I did github clone and cloned the repo to my local development system
3. Now i want to work on xyz tag ( and not on the latest/master) and push the changes to my repo. I did "git checkout " but it moves to a detached HEAD state and i am not sure how to move further form there.

Thanks in advance.
Sunil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, checkout the tag. `git checkout` takes any ref as a parameter, including tags.

```
git checkout {tag_name}
```

Then create a branch off that tag:

```
git checkout -b my_feature_branch
```

Then develop and push to origin as usual.

Comment: Is it possible to do it without branching ? I have to push the changes to my repo and then issue a pull request to project repo. In that case, it will issue a pull request to project to create a new branch. Is it possible to directly add code against the xyz tag.

Comment: A tag is just a pointer to a specific commit in the timeline. You can't commit more to that tag.

Comment: Also, tags shouldn't be moved. If you need to contribute an update to `xyz`, your changes will likely end up included in a tag like `xyz.1` (though this is of course up to the project maintainers).

Comment: Indeed, and if you insist on moving a tag, you should delete the old one first. But please, don't do this. Rewriting history in this way shouldn't be a neccessary part of your workflow.

Comment: I think i understand your point. So, i can create a new branch which will have all the changes till the tag xyz and start doing modification on top of it and once i am done with my changes, i can create a new tag to identify the timeline.

Comment: Any what should be the git push command to push the changes to github ? #git push <branhname> ?

Answer (score 1):

You should create a local branch for your work:

```
git checkout -b my-xyz xyz
```

This will create a new branch `my-xyz` from tag `xyz` and make it active.